# python 3 - beginner question if/else Q's with errors

Tags: python-3.x

Python 3 (not 2)

The question:
A company decided to give bonus of 5% to employee if his/her year of service is more than 5 years.
Ask user for their salary and year of service and print the net bonus amount.

There is an answer on the website but when I run the given answer there is an error..also tried all kinds of "corrected" versions but each time there is a different error. I guess there is a couple of errors..

```
print ("enter salary")
salary = input()
print ("enter year of service")
yos = input()
if yos>5:
    print ("bonus is"),0.05*salary
else:
    print ("no bonus")
```

please help with the corrected code (:
thank you

Comment: `input` returns a string. You need to convert to a number: `salary = int(input())` or `salary = float(input())`. Same for `yos`.

Comment: The website may show the code as correct because older versions of python did not need the conversion.

Comment: thanks! tried it as: 
print ("enter salary")
salary = int(input())
print ("enter year of service")
yos = int(input())
if yos>5:
    print ("bonus is"),0.05*salary
else:
    print ("no bonus")

after run:
enter salary
5000
enter year of service
6
>bonus is

and stops right there with no continue..

Comment: The `print` statement is also outdated. Use the more modern f-string: `print(f"bonus is {0.05 * salary}")`

Comment: You might find these links helpful: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Answer (score 0):

```
a=int(input("Enter salary")) 
b=int(input("Enter year of service"))
c=a+a/20 #a/20 gives 5%
if(b>5):
    print(c)
else:
    print(a)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?